# Thrown rod in engine block, can I drive it one mile?

Tags: engine, car, rod

My 2012 fusion overheated and a rod disconnected/snapped off, I have no idea if I'm saying any of that correctly, but from the word of a trusted mechanic friend, this is what has happened. I got a new car and just need to move the old car one mile to a residential area to get it picked up and junked- trying to avoid a $100+ towing fee to move it one silly mile. My big question is will the car make it, and will I not die in the process? I have no other way to move it other than drive it or get it towed.

Comment: Why don't you get help from a friend to tow it with their car? That is permitted in UK, subject to various legal requirements. But if the car is to be junked, why do you care if it will make it under its own power? Just go ahead and try.

Answer (score 2):

A thrown rod is (obviously) a very serious engine problem.  It's possible that it won't even start at this point.  It's also possible it will start and die after a few seconds.  It's also possible that you may be able to drive it a short distance before it fails completely.

Basically there is no way to know for sure.  At this point you have nothing to lose by trying it other than possibly making a mess on the street if the oil pan gets ripped open.

Comment: Or being the cause of a major accident if you loose control...

Comment: As noted the engine is dead, nothing to lose trying to drive it.  As a boy, I drove an Olds V8  about 3 miles with a piston missing , Slow and very loud bad sounds but it went. The piston remains subsequently drained out with the oil ,antifreeze mix.

Answer (score 1):

I've driven a car with a thrown rod about a mile, but I was going 60 mph when it blew.  There was a trail of oil from it puking out the engine.  I couldn't really accelerate much because the engine would speed up quickly and vibrate like crazy, so I kept it at an idle as much as I could.

Worst case, go buy a $15 tow strap and tow it with another car.  One person in the towed vehicle to run the steering wheel and brakes, and obviously one person in the towing vehicle.